# Optimizing searching for the database?

Tags: database, optimization

**EDIT for clarification:** the `regions` will have an (x,y)-coordinate range, which is used to determine where they are, and compare to where the user is. And the databases can technically be basically anything, I guess. Let's just call them "variables" or "objects". I don't think it matters much for the purposes of the question.

---

OK, theoretical story time.

So, let's say that there's 1 database, per `region`, and a `region` covers a 10 square mile section of the Earth, overlapping 1 mile at each edge with another `region` (thus, overlapping with 2 regions at a corner, yes). References to each of these databases are stored in an array. Afterall, I don't anticipate the Earth's number of "regions" to change any time soon. Who cares about the logistics of that. Moral of the story: There's a **lot** of databases.

I need to choose the database that corresponds to my `region`, and get the contents of it.

How do I do that (conceptually), or what method should I use to do that, without linearly searching through each and every bloody region each time I need to query my `region`'s database?

I know of Quicksearch, but is there an even more efficient way to do this search?

How should I set it up, considering there is an x and y axis to compare against, since we are only mapping the surface of the Earth, in this theoretical situation? Should I just search through one axis at a time, finding the horizontal strip of regions, and then search through the other axis, finding the exact `region(s)` of database(s) that should be queried for information?

Or, is there a search that can effectively do both at the same time? Is it possible to multi-thread searching both axes, since they are not reliant on each other?

Comment: I think you are very confused about the notions of "database" and "table".  I can't really figure out what you want to do.  However, R-Tree Indexes are a common structure for GIS indexes.

Comment: You can use a simple quadtree to index the databases based on co-ordinate ranges, and assuming a region has co-ordinates too you can use them to search your quadtree.

Comment: quadtree and R-Tree. I'll look both of those up. I appreciate it. I made an edit to try and clarify the question. Thanks for the feedback.